# "real" execution time limit

Tags: php, execution-time

Using [**set_time_limit()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or **max_execution_time**, does not "really" limits (except on Windows) the execution time, because as stated in PHP manual:

> Note:
>
> The **set_time_limit()** function and the configuration directive
>   **max_execution_time** only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using **system()**, stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

A solution is [proposed in PHP comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#105569) to have a "real" execution time limit like what I'm looking for, but I found it unclear/confusing.

Comment: A real execution time limit is set by the system executing the process. It can kill the process if the limit is reached (also known as hard limit). It's a real limit then, normally based on CPU time, that is actual time consumed by a process (not exactly how long the process already runs).

Comment: The solution suggested in [the comment you are talking about](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#105569) looks good to me - as long as you have POSIX and pcntl functions available. What exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: Looking more thoroughly at the suggestion in PHP manual comments was helpful :) I didn't understand at first how it was working (I'm not used to threads handling).

Comment: If you need to control some loop based process you can use just simple timer.

Comment: You could get pretty close to implementing this with a tick function, but it'd be a hack.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php

Comment: I'm asking for explanations on the "PHP comments solution", or any another solution. However I think that I've understood quite well how the "PHP comments solution" works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but as far as I understand you ask for explanation of the "PHP comments" solution code.

The trick is to spawn a child process, using **pcntl_fork** function, which will terminate the original (parent) process after some timeout. Function **pcntl_fork** returns process id of newly created child process inside a parent process execution thread and zero inside child process execution thread. That means parent process will execute the code under **if** statement and the child process will execute code under **else**. And as we can see from the code, the parent process will perform endless loop while child process will wait 5 seconds and then kill his parent. So basically you want to do something like this:

```
$real_execution_time_limit = 60; // one minute

if (pcntl_fork())
{
    // some long time code which should be
    // terminated after $real_execution_time_limit seconds passed if it's not
    // finished by that time
}
else
{
    sleep($real_execution_time_limit);
    posix_kill(posix_getppid(), SIGKILL); 
}
```

I hope I've exlained it well. Let me know if you sill have question regarding this solution.